# What is this odd error in the console: "ignoring singular matrix..."

Tags: swiftui, xcode13.3

I keep getting this message in the Xcode console when "Tap Me" is hit.

Is this a bug? Am I doing something wrong? Any thoughts?

```
ignoring singular matrix: ProjectionTransform(m11: 5e-324, m12: 0.0, m13: 0.0, m21: 0.0, m22: 5e-324, m23: 0.0, m31: 10.5, m32: 0.0, m33: 1.0)
```

This is the code that illustrates the problem, certainly related to the animation. Xcode version: 13.3, on Monterey: 12.3.1

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var letter = "A"
    @State var isAnimating: Bool = false
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button("Tap Me") {
                if letter == "A" {
                    letter = "B"
                } else {
                    letter = "A"
                }
            }.font(.largeTitle)
          
            Text(letter).font(.largeTitle).scaleEffect( isAnimating ? 1.0 : 0, anchor: .top)
 
            .onAppear {
                isAnimating = true
            }
            .onChange(of: letter) { _ in
                isAnimating = false
                withAnimation {
                    isAnimating = true
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: the error, seems to be due to the `.scaleEffect()`, specifically the `0`. Try this: `.scaleEffect( isAnimating ? 1.0 : 0.001, anchor: .top)`

Comment: @workingdogsupportUkraine Yep, that did it. Setting a non-zero values gets rid of the error.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

As the dog mentions, changing the 0 in:

```
scaleEffect( isAnimating ? 1.0 : 0 )
```

to

```
scaleEffect( isAnimating ? 1.0 : 0.001 )
```

gets rid of the error. Still, you'd think this would be better handled by the library.